# TCPDF not catching PHP variables via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, variables, pdf, tcpdf

I'm sending user data via jQuery to TCPDF, but it does not display any value received from jQuery in the PDF file.

I have even tried to capture the value in a session variable but it still doesn't display. Where am I going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="p">
    FOO
    <input type="text" id="nop" />
</div>

 <div id="e_table">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th><h3>ABC</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>PQR</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>XYS</h3></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Staff</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="as" /></td>
                        <td><label id="las">label</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Office</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="bo"/></td>
                        <td><label id="lbo">label</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Administrative</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="mca" /></td>
                        <td><label id="lmca">label</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#pdf').click(function() {                    
                    var nop = $('#nop').val();
                    var as = $('#as').val();
                    var las = $('#las').text();
                    var bo = $('#bo').val();
                    var lbo = $('#lbo').text();
                    var mca = $('#mca').val();
                    var lmca = $('#lmca').text();

                    var postData = {
                         "nop" : nop,
                         "as" : as,
                         "las" : las,
                         "bo" : bo,
                         "lbo" : lbo,
                         "mca" : mca,
                         "lmca" : lmca
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "pdf.php",
                            data: postData, 
                            success: function(data){
                                window.open("pdf.php"); 
                            }
                        });


        });
```

TCPDF pdf.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

//============================================================+
// Author: Nicola Asuni
//
// (c) Copyright:
//               Nicola Asuni
//               Tecnick.com s.r.l.
//               Via Della Pace, 11
//               09044 Quartucciu (CA)
//               ITALY
//               www.tecnick.com
//               info@tecnick.com
//============================================================+

/**
 * @author Nicola Asuni
 * @since 2009-03-20
 */

require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {


    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 8);
        $this->SetTextColor(247, 147, 29); 


        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'ABC', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('ABC');
$pdf->SetTitle('ABC');
$pdf->SetSubject('ABC');
$pdf->SetKeywords('ABC');


// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(false);


$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 5, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
// ---------------------------------------------------------


// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


//request parameters
    $nop = strip_tags($_POST['nop']);
    $_SESSION['nop'] = $nop;
    $nop = $_SESSION['nop'];
    $as = strip_tags($_POST['as']);
    $las = strip_tags($_POST['las']);
    $bo = strip_tags($_POST['bo']);
    $lbo = strip_tags($_POST['lbo']);
    $mca = strip_tags($_POST['mca']);
    $lmca = strip_tags($_POST['lmca']);

$tbl = <<<EOF
          <div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>FOO</td>
                        <td>$nop</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>ABC</h3></th>
                                        <th><h3>PQR</h3></th>
                                        <th><h3>XYS</h3></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Staff</td>
                        <td>$as</td>
                        <td>$las</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Office</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Administrative</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
         </div>
EOF;

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');

$txt = $nop . 'This';

 // print a block of text using Write()
$pdf->Write($h=0, $txt, $link='', $fill=0, $align='C', $ln=true, $stretch=0, $firstline=false, $firstblock=false, $maxh=0); 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('ABC.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE                                                
//============================================================+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling your pdf.php 2 times, one with the post data, and one without

```
$.ajax({ // call 1, with post data
    type: "POST",
    url: "pdf.php",
    data: postData, 
    success: function(data){
        window.open("pdf.php"); // call 2, without post data
    }
});
```

what you can do is to remove your ajax request, and send the data via GET instead with

```
var getString = "nop=" + nop "&as=" + as; // .....
window.open("pdf.php?" + getString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This worked. I just want to know if I can hide the parameters in the url string?

Comment: @input nope sorry, not with get. depends why you want to hide, but it is easy to look at the post values that is sent to

Answer (score 0):

Try
    print_r($_POST);

and put it somewhere at the beginning of the php file where you build the pdf.
This helps you understand which values arrives and which values don't

Answer (score 0):

> I have even tried to capture the value in a session variable but it still doesn't display. Where am I going wrong?

It should work. Did you miss `session_start()`?

Another approach is to generate PDF in you ajax request and output filename which you would open with `window.open()`